# Somatory of "n" math operation results without VBA

Tags: math, excel-formula, sum, series, integral

I need an algorithm only "function-based" (no VBA) to find the value of "S" as explained below.

- Value "A"
- Value "B"
- Value "C"
- Value "D"
- j = increment - increases by 1 for each time the equation is executed;
- n = Qtt of iterations = Number of times the main equation must be executed
- S = Sum = Sum of all the "i" results of equations for each variation of "j"

The equation for each line is: = [A*(B+8)]* [C+[D*(j-0.5)]]

The operation is based on accumulating the results of the equation for each value of "j" that increases at a rate of 1. See the following example:

For: A = 2, B = 3, C = 4, D = 5 and n = 7, we have:

- for i=1: =[2*(3+8)]* [4+[5*(1-0.5)]] = 143
- for i=2: =[2*(3+8)]* [4+[5*(2-0.5)]] = 253
- for i=3: =[2*(3+8)]* [4+[5*(3-0.5)]] = 363
- for i=4: =[2*(3+8)]* [4+[5*(4-0.5)]] = 473
- for i=5: =[2*(3+8)]* [4+[5*(5-0.5)]] = 583
- for i=6: =[2*(3+8)]* [4+[5*(6-0.5)]] = 693
- for i=7: =[2*(3+8)]* [4+[5*(7-0.5)]] = 803

So "S" will be: S = 143 + 253 + 363 + 473 + 583 + 693 + 803 = 3311

I know using VBA would be relatively easy to find the "S" value, but the thing is that using VBA is unwanted in this case. Maybe the math reasoning to reach my goal is the calculation of integrals but I also couldn't find a native Excel function to go thru this path

I tried to associate functions like OFFSET, SERIESSUM, FACT and even integrals and I couldn't get there.

Comment: Is there an upper bound on `n`? If so, it is straightforward -- just have a row for each `j` up to the upper bound and use something like `sumif` to decide which terms to add. If there isn't such an upper bound, I don't see how to do this without VBA.

Answer (score 2):

[image: Equation]

As what I understand and a straightforward set up as image
copy paste to column I to many rows you want

```
=IF(H2="","",$J$2*($K$2+8)*($L$2+($M$2*(H2-0.5))))
```

copy paste to cell H2

```
=(ROW(INDEX(A:A,1):INDEX(A:A,G1)))
```

you can change the nth value you want in cell G1
and straightforward sum for S value

Comment: Nice, if using Excel 365, you can mod your formula to: `=SUM($J$2*($K$2+8)*($L$2+($M$2*(SEQUENCE(7)-0.5))))` where n is the 7 inside the SEQUENCE().

Comment: =IF(AH2="","",$AJ$2*($AK$2+8)*($AL$2+($AM$2*(SEQUENCE($AG$1)-0.5)))) I tried like  this and much better fully automation thanks @mark fitzpatrick